# Getting "None" when parsing out data on python,BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For a while have been trying to make a python program which can split data from websites. I came across the `bs4` library for python and decided to use it for that job.

The problem is that I always get as a result `None` which is something that I cannot understand

I want to get only one word which is in `a` @href, located in a div class and for that, I wrote a function which is like that:

```
def run(self):
    response = requests.get(self.url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    finalW = soup.find('a', attrs={'class': 'target'})
    print(finalW)
```

With this code, I expect to get a word, but it just returns `None`.
It is highly possible, too, that I had made a mistake with the path to this directory, so I post an image with the thing I want to extract from the HTML:

[image]

Comment: You should add raw data, not image link or screenshot.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: have you checked that this html element is there in the source code or if its added later by some javascript/ajax call whic his modifying the DOM object. requests will only get the original source. you wont get any updates or modifications that add or modify elements of the original source.

Comment: Have already checked for that, Chris Doyle. When I use finde_all command I clearly see all A href in that HTML file, including the thing I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

When `bs4` is not able to find the query, it returns None.

In your case the html is more or less like this.

```
...
<div class='target'>
    <a href="somelonglink">neededlink</a>
    <a href="someotherlink">notneededlink</a>
...
</div>
...
```

`soup.find('a', attrs={'class': 'target'})` thus will not be able to math your query as there are not attrs in `a`.

If you are certain that your link is first in below query.

```
soup.find('div', {'class': 'target'}).find('a')['href']
```

Comment: Again get an error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I am certain that if your html is what you say in image is, this will work.

Comment: No, it does not. However, I found my mistake. Many thanks man!!

Comment: What was your mistake?

Comment: well, I realized that I get none type of object because of the fact that there is not an object. So I find out that I should first get in this, in my case "target",  div class and then looking for something in it. As far the result, I just include two lines of, which show the program where to look for div class"target" ' s parent div class. Many thanks again